# mbed drivers for a NUCLEO_WB55RG board

Tags: arm, embedded, mbed

When creating an `mbed` application, is it possible to see the code that is used for the specific device?

E.g., for the NUCLEO_WB55RG I would like to see the ST drivers that are used.

I took a look in the `mbed` docs but did not see anything regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the source, of course you can "see" it.  Check your link map to see what is included in the build or use a debugger to step "in-to" the third-party code - if the source is available it should be shown as you enter it.

Moreover any of the code included that is open-source, you will be able to access the source, even if it is delivered to you as object code.  For example in your case, from https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-WB55RG/ follow the link https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_STM/README.md